# What is the inner dashed line on this helicopter chart?

Tags: helicopter, aeronautical-charts

[image]Inside the delta for KSGR is another blue dashed circle. What is this?

Comment: Where did you get this image from? It looks like a composite of two charts...

Comment: Did you check the chart legend for the different line types?

Comment: Oh good point, yes it's from foreflight. and there's actually three charts superimposed, the sectional in back, then the US helicopter route chart with the white background (https://aeronav.faa.gov/content/aeronav/heli_files/PDFs/Houston_Heli_9_P.pdf) and finally overlayed on that is Foreflight's aeronatutical. What I'm concluding is that the US Helicopter chart has the wrong Delta airspace size for SGR

Answer (score 5):

First of all, sorry for the confusing original image. It comes from foreflight and has three charts superimposed. 1) the sectional, 2) the houston helicopter route chart (white background) and 3) the foreflight aeronautical chart showing the airpace again. I'm attaching a simpler one which shows just the sectional and the helicopter route chart.

It turns out that the helicopter route chart is simply out of date (!?). I called the Sugarland tower and they confirmed that 2 years ago the Delta expanded from a 4.2 mile radius to a 5 mile radius. The Helicopter route chart still depicts this as 4.2 (https://aeronav.faa.gov/content/aeronav/heli_files/PDFs/Houston_Heli_9_P.pdf) Hopefully the next edition will correct this.

[image]

Comment: The new map comes out in September, and since the airspace modification is outlined in the Chart Supplement, I'd be pretty confident that this change will make it into the new chart.